# Facebook streamPublish window keeps resizing, hiding 'publish' and 'skip' buttons

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using streamPublish in my facebook app in a couple of places to post to the user's wall and to post to a friend's wall. It's been working fine for he past couple of months, but for the last few days the window keeps resizing in a downwards direction, hiding the publish and skip buttons off the bottom of the screen.

I have tried in IE, FF and chrome. It seems to be random - sometimes the window will open correctly, and sometimes it will resize off the bottom of the screen. I have noticed that in IE and chrome, the title bar of the window doesn't appear, so when this issue happens, there is no 'X' to click on to close the window, as well as no publish or skip buttons, so there is now way to close the window. FF does however have the title bar.

I found this bug on FB website:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15214

Could it be related?

Answer (score 0):

this also happened to me when the streamPublish  dialog raised in the place of a flash 
I just changed the place of the flash file or using  instead the iframe